# Process method not executing desired program

Tags: java

```
public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // print a message
            System.out.println("Executing VLC.exe");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe");
            // print another message
            System.out.println("VLC should now open.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)   at
 java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)     at
 java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)     at
 java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)     at test2.main(test2.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system
 cannot find the file specified     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native
 Method)    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)     at
 java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)    ... 5 more***
```

But this program runs notepad.exe and associated text files rather easily. So can it only run programs in Win32?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

here is the pic with the dos ...

Comment: how about running `cmd /c start "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"` and `cmd /c start C:\Program^ Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe` in cmd?

Comment: Actually, a command like `cmd /c start C:\"Program Files"\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe` has to work. The double quotations force escaping the white space in "Program Files". Tested just now!

Comment: but i got it working by appending the original one to new String[]{ "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe",`"\"`"}

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of the white space in "Program Files".

You can avoid any problems like this by using the [Runtime#exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) that takes a String[]:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"});
```

That way you don't have to worry about quoting the file names. However, you still have to worry about quoting \ in the file names.

Comment: `"cmd", "/c", "start"`

what is the purpose of this?

Comment: and eclipse is still giving me the invalid sequence character error

Comment: after i changed it back to "\\" , it opened a new dos window with the directory as my byte code directory

Comment: try `cmd /c start C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe` in cmd and tell me what's the output, first.